# "Imprecise external abort" when performing ioread32 on AXI DMA

Tags: c, linux-kernel, xilinx, dma, vivado

I am using the [`openwifi`](https://github.com/open-sdr/openwifi) project and I am trying to extract data out of the FPGA (Zedboard) to the ZYNQ. Therefore, I added a AXI DMA in scatter gather mode to my block diagram with the following configuration:
[image]

The addresses are:

[image]

As far as I know, everything should be correctly configured and connected in Vivado. Because of the additional AXI DMA, I had to add it to the linux device tree:

```js
dma@80420000 {
        #dma-cells = <0x01>;
        clock-names = "s_axi_lite_aclk\0m_axi_sg_aclk\0m_axi_mm2s_aclk\0m_axi_s2mm_aclk";
        clocks = <0x02 0x11 0x02 0x11 0x02 0x11 0x02 0x11>;
        compatible = "xlnx,axi-dma-1.00.a";
        interrupt-names = "mm2s_introut\0s2mm_introut";
        interrupt-parent = <0x01>;
        interrupts = <0x00 0x27 0x04 0x00 0x28 0x04>;
        reg = <0x80420000 0x10000>;
        xlnx,addrwidth = <0x20>;
        xlnx,include-sg ;
        xlnx,sg-length-width = <0x0e>;
        phandle = <0x0c>;
        dma-channel@80420000 {
            compatible = "xlnx,axi-dma-mm2s-channel";
            dma-channels = <0x1>;
            interrupts = <0x00 0x44 0x04>;
            xlnx,datawidth = <0x40>;
            xlnx,device-id = <0x2>;
        };
        dma-channel@80420030 {
            compatible = "xlnx,axi-dma-s2mm-channel";
            dma-channels = <0x1>;
            interrupts = <0x00 0x45 0x04>;
            xlnx,datawidth = <0x40>;
            xlnx,device-id = <0x2>;
        };
};
```

2 AXI DMAs were already configured by openwifi (`dma@80410000` & `dma@80400000`). The complete **modified** device-tree can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/wchuBBQ6). The **original** tree by openwifi is [here](https://pastebin.com/rr2Pra3Q) (Due to the length I can't post it on SO).

My problem is that when I am trying to load the `xilinx_dma` driver into linux, I get the following error:

```js
Unhandled fault: imprecise external abort (0x406) at 0xb6f38000
pgd = df614000
[b6f38000] *pgd=1627f831, *pte=1ece359f, *ppte=1ece3e7e
Internal error: : 406 [#1] PREEMPT SMP ARM
Modules linked in: xilinx_dma(+) ad9361_drv mac80211 cfg80211 ipv6
CPU: 0 PID: 2093 Comm: insmod Not tainted 4.14.0-gb6e379910a11-dirty #2
Hardware name: Xilinx Zynq Platform
task: df7ff280 task.stack: d622c000
PC is at xilinx_dma_chan_reset+0x58/0x27c [xilinx_dma]
LR is at xilinx_dma_chan_reset+0x44/0x27c [xilinx_dma]
pc : [<bf17d600>]    lr : [<bf17d5ec>]    psr: 60060013
sp : d622dce0  ip : 00000000  fp : 00000001
r10: dfbb5094  r9 : 00000000  r8 : 00000000
r7 : 00000000  r6 : 00000000  r5 : 00000000  r4 : df493410
r3 : dec0de1c  r2 : 00000000  r1 : dfb89374  r0 : 00000058
Flags: nZCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment none
Control: 18c5387d  Table: 1f61404a  DAC: 00000051
Process insmod (pid: 2093, stack limit = 0xd622c210)
Stack: (0xd622dce0 to 0xd622e000)
dce0: df493410 d6023010 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 dfbb5094 bf17dff4
dd00: bf180dc0 df493410 bf180ca0 bf180cb4 014080c0 d6023018 d6023020 dfbb4d78
dd20: df572610 00000000 bf180c70 bf180c80 df576a50 cf73edc0 00000020 0000000e
dd40: 00000001 00000040 00000001 df572610 ffffffed bf182014 fffffdfb 00000000
dd60: 00000000 00000007 00000028 c03b2a20 df572610 c0c79fa8 c0c79fac bf182014
dd80: 00000000 c03b1240 df572610 bf182014 df572644 00000000 cf73d924 00000001
dda0: 00000000 c03b1394 00000000 bf182014 c03b12f0 c03af7a0 df491f58 df570ab4
ddc0: bf182014 d6ae7000 c0c1f458 c03b07a0 bf1810f8 00000000 bf185000 bf182014
dde0: 00000000 bf185000 d4b80600 c03b1c3c ffffe000 00000000 bf185000 c0101a20
de00: 00000000 00000000 c0c54234 c0c54220 c0994394 00000000 014000c0 e30a4000
de20: dfda5600 c0c54380 00000000 0000f730 c0c54380 c01af084 00000001 a0030013
de40: d4b80600 e3057000 bf1820c0 00000001 cf73d900 d4b80600 cf73d924 c018895c
de60: bf1820c0 cf73d924 00000001 d622df50 00000001 cf73d900 bf1820c0 c01875f0
de80: bf1820cc 00007fff bf1820c0 c0184b7c bf182108 00000000 bf1821c0 c0805304
dea0: bf1821f0 c0a0d880 bf18227c bf1821d4 c0998804 00000000 bf181104 bf000001
dec0: 0004bad4 00000000 d622df48 bf180024 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000
dee0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
df00: 00000000 00000000 7fffffff 00000000 00000003 0046e398 0000017b c0107b24
df20: d622c000 00000000 00000000 c0188008 7fffffff 00000000 00000003 00000000
df40: 00000000 e3057000 0004bad4 00000000 e305c1b7 e3057000 0004bad4 e30a223c
df60: e30a2020 e308d180 00008000 00008310 00000000 00000000 00000000 00002bb0
df80: 00000034 00000035 00000020 0000001b 00000018 00000000 be8646c4 be864844
dfa0: 45194a00 c0107960 be8646c4 be864844 00000003 0046e398 00000000 00000000
dfc0: be8646c4 be864844 45194a00 0000017b 0047adc8 00000000 0046ab60 00000000
dfe0: be864670 be864660 00465177 b6f312b2 80030030 00000003 00000000 00000000
[<bf17d600>] (xilinx_dma_chan_reset [xilinx_dma]) from [<bf17dff4>] (xilinx_dma_probe+0x424/0xb04 [xilinx_dma])
[<bf17dff4>] (xilinx_dma_probe [xilinx_dma]) from [<c03b2a20>] (platform_drv_probe+0x50/0xac)
[<c03b2a20>] (platform_drv_probe) from [<c03b1240>] (driver_probe_device+0x238/0x2e8)
[<c03b1240>] (driver_probe_device) from [<c03b1394>] (__driver_attach+0xa4/0xa8)
[<c03b1394>] (__driver_attach) from [<c03af7a0>] (bus_for_each_dev+0x4c/0x9c)
[<c03af7a0>] (bus_for_each_dev) from [<c03b07a0>] (bus_add_driver+0x188/0x20c)
[<c03b07a0>] (bus_add_driver) from [<c03b1c3c>] (driver_register+0x78/0xf4)
[<c03b1c3c>] (driver_register) from [<c0101a20>] (do_one_initcall+0x44/0x168)
[<c0101a20>] (do_one_initcall) from [<c018895c>] (do_init_module+0x60/0x1f0)
[<c018895c>] (do_init_module) from [<c01875f0>] (load_module+0x1b8c/0x23a0)
[<c01875f0>] (load_module) from [<c0188008>] (SyS_finit_module+0x9c/0xb4)
[<c0188008>] (SyS_finit_module) from [<c0107960>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x48)
Code: e5933000 e0833005 e5933000 f57ff04f (e5943000) 
---[ end trace e3cdb0330d71dd39 ]---
```

I identified that the error occurs in this function inside `xilinx_dma.c`:

```cs
/* IO accessors */
static inline u32 dma_read(struct xilinx_dma_chan *chan, u32 reg)
{
    return ioread32(chan->xdev->regs + reg); // Here
}
```

So the `ioread32` doesn't work. **My question is: Why is this and what can I do about it?**

If I remove the new AXI DMA from the device tree or change its `compatible` property to something random it works fine. So I suppose something has to be wrongly configured in the AXI DMA I added.

Comment: If you need further information, let me know and I am happy to provide it

Comment: The external abort can happen when clock to a module are not enabled. It is also possible that some bus access (Trustzone) may prohibit peripherals.  I believe the FSR (fault status register) is somewhere in the oops.  You can look up the FSR value to get some further info.

Comment: I managed to fix the problem by reducing the address ranges from all DMAs from 64k to 32k (which is more then enough).